# Can I convert string to time having times greater than 24 hours in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, time, google-bigquery

I have a column with records of time in string data type. The times are written as 'HH:MM:SS'. The data range is, for example, 00:00:00 and 1000:00:00. I want to change the data type to an appropriate time data type that yields the format HH:MM:SS so I can execute filters like ascending and descending order that will make analyzing the data much easier and without errors.

Example data table:

Table name: Run_Time

Field(s): ..., duration[String]

records: 100,000

| row | duration |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 06:45:30 |
| 2 | 12:56:00 |
| 3 | 23:00:00 |
| 4 | 18:12:09 |
| 5 | 98:59:59 |

... etc.

Using Google BigQuery, this is what I've tried:

```
SELECT
  CAST(duration AS TIME)
FROM Run_Time
```

Result:
Error. Invalid time string "566:59:00".

Expected result:
Successful query. Applied to all data in field 'duration' (This is how I'd imagine the console will respond.)

Error reviewing:
According to Google's reference guide, TIME data type can only contain values in the range 00:00:00 to 23:59:59. Now that I understand why the error was produced, I need a solution that accepts the condition where time can exceed 23:59:59. SAFE_CAST is one option I've considered. However, SAFE_CAST will yield null values where values do not meet the data type conditions.

Is there a solution to fix or correct the error in BigQuery?
If for reasons the problem cannot be solved by BigQuery, what alternative solutions would you suggest I can try to change data type format?

Comment: Why do you specifically want to generate a `time` out of this string?

Comment: For personal use. To explain so everyone can understand my problem and desired outcome, I need the field to contain time data like you would see on a stopwatch. Then, I can apply analysis filters like order by ascending or descending to check that the numbers are listed in the correct filter order.

Comment: Then you could turn them to a number of seconds, for example. Or better yet, use [the interval datatype](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#interval_type)?

Comment: what would be the wanted result of "566:59:00" be?

Comment: The result of "566:59:00", from a string, should be 566:59:00 (a readable number like time that other programs like spreadsheet can recognize and able to perform numeric calculations).

Comment: then why convert it in the first place, the spreadsheet can do it as well as sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the second suggestion from @GMB in comment may be the easiest; [using interval](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/interval_functions)

```
with my_data as (
  SELECT JUSTIFY_INTERVAL(INTERVAL '566:59:00' HOUR TO SECOND) AS i, -- 0-0 23 14:59:0
  UNION ALL SELECT JUSTIFY_INTERVAL(INTERVAL '66:59:00' HOUR TO SECOND) -- 0-0 2 18:59:0
  UNION ALL SELECT JUSTIFY_INTERVAL(INTERVAL '66:559:00' HOUR TO SECOND) -- 0-0 3 3:19:0
  UNION ALL SELECT JUSTIFY_INTERVAL(INTERVAL '66:59:4242' HOUR TO SECOND) -- 0-0 2 20:9:42
)  

SELECT * FROM my_data ORDER BY i
```

returns values in correct order

```
0-0 2 18:59:0
0-0 2 20:9:42
0-0 3 3:19:0
0-0 23 14:59:0
```

Answer (score 0):

The values you hope to get are invalid time values '98:59:59' is not a  valid time. You don't need to convert to time to perform your filter/sort; just need comparable strings; can you try padding it on the left with zeroes to make it the same length:

```
select LPAD(duration,10,'0')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 options:

1. Use a number of seconds (int64 data type)
2. Use an Interval data type (i.e. designed to cater for durations)

Pros of INT64 :

- a simple and straightforward data type that represents a duration in seconds as a single integer value
- easy to filter and sort using standard SQL operators and functions
- efficient in terms of storage and computation

Cons of INT64:

- no inherent information about the units of duration (except number of seconds)
- maximum duration is approx. 292 years

Pros of INTERVAL:

- shows duration as a combination of years, months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds, providing more information about the duration
- much larger maximum (i.e. much bigger then 292 years)

Cons of INTERVAL:

- requires more storage space and computation
- arguably not as easy to filter using standard SQL operators and functions as INT64 (but: more intuitive "> interval '1 year'")

Jumping to the the assumption that you would need to keep the existing column - AND - it will remain the way the data is created, then a "computed column" approach could be used e.g. either of these

```
ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable 
ADD COLUMN duration_seconds INT64 AS 
        (SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(duration, ':')[OFFSET(0)] AS INT64) * 3600 
        + SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(duration, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) * 60 
        + SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(duration, ':')[OFFSET(2)] AS INT64)
        );


ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable 
ADD COLUMN duration_interval INTERVAL AS 
        (MAKE_INTERVAL(0, 0, SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(duration, ':')[OFFSET(0)] AS INT64)
        , SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(duration, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64)
        , SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(duration, ':')[OFFSET(2)] AS INT64))
        );
```

these can be adapted to other approaches if not using computed columns

Comment: Thank you for explaining the different details about INT64 and INTERVAL. I have a question about your sample query. In the line (MAKE_INTERVAL( 0, 0, SAFE_CAST... etc., is there suppose to be another 0 following the second 0? I understand that MAKE_INTERVAL follows this (year, month, day, hour, minute, second).

Comment: Not all parameters are mandatory when using MAKE_INTERVAL, it constructs an INTERVAL using INT64 values for year, month, day, hour, minute, and second. All arguments are optional with a default value of 0. BUT going left to right you have to use at least the comma so that your values align to the correct time unit. e.g. `make_interval(null,null,12)` is valid *I note you at one point chose this as the answer, but is there no value in my answer at all?*

Comment: I understand now. All answers I've received are valuable insights and have been noted. I'm an amateur using the features in Stackoverflow. If it would allow me, I would mark more than one answer as acceptable, neither one more valuable than the other, in helping me find or create a solution I need for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After carefully reviewing suggested answers, proposals from the comments, trying myself to apply the sample queries, and taking a bit of recess. I've come up with a solution by understanding a little more about the data types: Interval and Time (and other data types related to Time).

I've tried casting to Interval.

```
SELECT
  duration,
  CAST(duration AS INTERVAL) AS time_interval
FROM Run_Time
```

This produced intervals in alias time_interval that looks like this:

0-0 0 0:0:0

Read as [year]-[month] [day] [hour]:[minute]:[second]

Although I would like only the hh:mm:ss part from the interval, I think accompanying duration (string data type) with time_interval (interval data type) together in a table is suitable enough to solve my stated problem. For instance, if I want to know  the max duration in hh:mm:ss, I can order the time_interval in descending and read the duration next to the time_interval. Both duration and time_interval will display the same time. However, because duration is a string data type, it is difficult to execute calculations when working with data recognized as text or string.

I hope this answer can help others find the solution they need or guide them to discover more innovative solutions when encountering a problem like this.